# laravel can't find database directory

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have quite a weird problem. I'm using 5.4 version of laravel, currently working from my notebook windows 10, on the other devices mac and pc I do not have this problem.

So, the problem is when i try to seed the database I get this strange error which says

[ErrorException] include(C:\Users\nathaniel\Desktop\LaraProjects\cms\vendor\composer/../../atabase/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php): failed to o pen stream: No such file or directory

As you can see instead of \database it's saying \atabase and I have no clue why. While doing php artisan migrate:refresh --seed migrates everything but when it comes to seeding it fails:

php artisan migrate:refresh --seed Rolling back: 2014_07_02_230147_migration_cartalyst_sentinel Rolled back: 2014_07_02_230147_migration_cartalyst_sentinel Migrating: 2014_07_02_230147_migration_cartalyst_sentinel Migrated: 2014_07_02_230147_migration_cartalyst_sentinel

[ErrorException] include(C:\Users\nathaniel\Desktop\LaraProjects\cms\vendor\composer/../../atabase/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php): failed to o pen stream: No such file or directory

I've tried dumping autoload and clearing cache but the problem is still here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant add comment, anyway, try check folder, what name is exactly `database`, next open `composer.json` and check this params

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

After try again `composer dump-autoload` and check.

Answer (score 1):

First try to upgrade composer: `composer self-update`

I don't know the reason of this weird bug, but you can fix it by providing full path to database in `composer.json` (worked for buggy composer version 1.4.2)

```
"classmap": [
       "C:\\Users\\nathaniel\\Desktop\\LaraProjects\\cms\\database"
],
```